# How can I create a table with 64 combinations with python?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a table that one column is choosing 3 out of a list [1,2,3,4] randomly with replacement. Then another column is only changing the middle number.

For example,

```
column 1   column2
111         121
111         131
111         141
121         111
121         131
...
444         414
444         424
444         434
```

The total should be 64 combinations. I tried combinations_with_replacement()

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
ref = list(it.combinations_with_replacement(lst, 3))
>>> print(ref)
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 4), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 3), (1, 3, 4), (1, 4, 4), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3), (2, 2, 4), (2, 3, 3), (2, 3, 4), (2, 4, 4), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 4), (3, 4, 4), (4, 4, 4)]
>>> len(ref)
20
```

but it did not work as I wanted... Any suggestions on how to change?

Thanks

Comment: Why it did not work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Just as a hint:

```
col1 = []
col2 = []
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        for k in range(4):
            col1.append([i + 1, j + 1, k + 1])
            for l in range(3):
                col2.append([i + 1, (j + l + 1) % 4 + 1, k + 1])
print ("The list\n" + str(col1) + "\nhas " + str(len(col1)) + " entries")
print ("The list\n" + str(col2) + "\nhas " + str(len(col2)) + " entries")
```

This yields:

```
The list
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 4], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 1], [1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 4, 1], [1, 4, 2], [1, 4, 3], [1, 4, 4], [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 4], [2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 4], [2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 2], [2, 3, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 1], [2, 4, 2], [2, 4, 3], [2, 4, 4], [3, 1, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 3], [3, 1, 4], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 2], [3, 2, 3], [3, 2, 4], [3, 3, 1], [3, 3, 2], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 4], [3, 4, 1], [3, 4, 2], [3, 4, 3], [3, 4, 4], [4, 1, 1], [4, 1, 2], [4, 1, 3], [4, 1, 4], [4, 2, 1], [4, 2, 2], [4, 2, 3], [4, 2, 4], [4, 3, 1], [4, 3, 2], [4, 3, 3], [4, 3, 4], [4, 4, 1], [4, 4, 2], [4, 4, 3], [4, 4, 4]]
has 64 entries
The list
[[1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 1], [1, 4, 1], [1, 2, 2], [1, 3, 2], [1, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 3], [1, 4, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [1, 4, 4], [1, 3, 1], [1, 4, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 3, 2], [1, 4, 2], [1, 1, 2], [1, 3, 3], [1, 4, 3], [1, 1, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 4, 4], [1, 1, 4], [1, 4, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 4, 2], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2], [1, 4, 3], [1, 1, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 4], [1, 1, 4], [1, 2, 4], [1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2], [1, 3, 2], [1, 1, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 3], [1, 1, 4], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 2, 1], [2, 3, 1], [2, 4, 1], [2, 2, 2], [2, 3, 2], [2, 4, 2], [2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3], [2, 4, 3], [2, 2, 4], [2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 4], [2, 3, 1], [2, 4, 1], [2, 1, 1], [2, 3, 2], [2, 4, 2], [2, 1, 2], [2, 3, 3], [2, 4, 3], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 4], [2, 1, 4], [2, 4, 1], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1], [2, 4, 2], [2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 4, 3], [2, 1, 3], [2, 2, 3], [2, 4, 4], [2, 1, 4], [2, 2, 4], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1], [2, 3, 1], [2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3], [2, 1, 4], [2, 2, 4], [2, 3, 4], [3, 2, 1], [3, 3, 1], [3, 4, 1], [3, 2, 2], [3, 3, 2], [3, 4, 2], [3, 2, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 4, 3], [3, 2, 4], [3, 3, 4], [3, 4, 4], [3, 3, 1], [3, 4, 1], [3, 1, 1], [3, 3, 2], [3, 4, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 3, 3], [3, 4, 3], [3, 1, 3], [3, 3, 4], [3, 4, 4], [3, 1, 4], [3, 4, 1], [3, 1, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 4, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 2], [3, 4, 3], [3, 1, 3], [3, 2, 3], [3, 4, 4], [3, 1, 4], [3, 2, 4], [3, 1, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 2], [3, 3, 2], [3, 1, 3], [3, 2, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 1, 4], [3, 2, 4], [3, 3, 4], [4, 2, 1], [4, 3, 1], [4, 4, 1], [4, 2, 2], [4, 3, 2], [4, 4, 2], [4, 2, 3], [4, 3, 3], [4, 4, 3], [4, 2, 4], [4, 3, 4], [4, 4, 4], [4, 3, 1], [4, 4, 1], [4, 1, 1], [4, 3, 2], [4, 4, 2], [4, 1, 2], [4, 3, 3], [4, 4, 3], [4, 1, 3], [4, 3, 4], [4, 4, 4], [4, 1, 4], [4, 4, 1], [4, 1, 1], [4, 2, 1], [4, 4, 2], [4, 1, 2], [4, 2, 2], [4, 4, 3], [4, 1, 3], [4, 2, 3], [4, 4, 4], [4, 1, 4], [4, 2, 4], [4, 1, 1], [4, 2, 1], [4, 3, 1], [4, 1, 2], [4, 2, 2], [4, 3, 2], [4, 1, 3], [4, 2, 3], [4, 3, 3], [4, 1, 4], [4, 2, 4], [4, 3, 4]]
has 192 entries
```

Answer (score 0):

[itertools.combinations_with_replacement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) will sort the results and remove duplicates. (1,2,1) will be sorted to (1,1,2) and removed because (1,1,2) already exists. What you are looking for is [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
ref = list(it.product(lst, repeat=3))
>>> len(ref)
64
```

Comment: Thanks! I also want to try with a str list. If I change [1,2,3,4] to ['abcd'], it shows "'int' object is not iterable" how should I change?

Comment: My bad, it should be it.product(lst, repeat=3) and not it.product(lst, 3), I have updated the answer. You should change [1,2,3,4] to ['a','b','c','d'] and not ['abcd']